# Are Scala functions that run on an Spark Array parallelized?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

To map a function agains all elements of an RDD it is required to first convert the RDD to an Array type using collect method :

```
scala> val x = sc.parallelize(List(List("a"), List("b"), List("c", "d")))
x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[String]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:12

scala> x.collect()
res0: Array[List[String]] = Array(List(a), List(b), List(c, d))

scala> x.flatMap(y => y)
res3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = FlatMappedRDD[3] at flatMap at <console>:15
```

Are all operations on the Array type in above example "x" run in parallel ?

Comment: `x.collect()` returns a Scala collection, but since you don't assign it to a variable, it gets thrown away. `x.flatMap(y => y)` applies a transformation to `x` and returns a new RDD, but since transformations in Spark are lazy, this doesn't trigger any activity. Transformations and actions against RDDs *are* run in parallel, but if you did `map()` against the output of `x.collect()` (a plain Array), that would not be run in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To map a function agains all elements of an RDD it is required to first convert the RDD to an Array type using collect method

No, it isn't. RDD has `map` method.

> Are all operations on the Array type in above example "x" run in parallel ?

There are no operations on the Array type in the above example. `x` is still an RDD, you throw away the array created by `x.collect()`. If you call `x.collect().map(...)` or `x.collect().flatMap(...)` instead, the operations are not run in parallel.

Generally speaking, Spark does not affect operations on arrays or Scala collections in any way; only operations on RDDs are ever run in parallel. Of course, you can use e.g. Scala parallel collections to parallelize computations within a single node, but this is unrelated to Spark.

Answer (score 0):

In spark standalone applications (not REPL) you must change the order of operations.

first call `flatMap`and then `collect`.

[According to spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations), `flatMap`is a transformation and all transformations in Spark are lazy, in that they do not compute their results right away. the operation is delayed until a call of action methods like `collect`.
After calling `collect`spark parallelized all operation w.r.t `flatMap`.